# Yocto compilation taking so much time on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, yocto, ubuntu-22.04

**i am using hp victus 15. On VMware workstation 17 i gave 8 gb of ram and 6 core but still core-image-minimal took 18 hours to compile for first time is there any way to reduce this time**

i tried to change local.conf file for take all available core but got random error.

**is there anyway to source bitbake automatically when new terminal window is open**

Comment: 8 gb of ram is really low, just like 6 core ...

Comment: I wouldn't recommend VM, if you can use Container (Docker, for example), at least 16G of RAM. Virtual Machine alone already makes the process "slower".

Answer (score 0):

You can find tips on how to speed up the build [on the official documentation](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/speeding-up-build.html).

Additionally to this :

- If the `do_fetch` tasks are slow, be sure to have [download cache](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/singleindex.html#term-DL_DIR) enabled, and improve your Internet speed
- If the `do_compile` tasks are slow, add more CPU
- If recipes parsing and general execution is slow, ensure you are on an adapted filesystem and disk (SSD)
- If everything is rebuilt each time, be sure to have your [`SSTATE_DIR`](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/structure.html?highlight=sstate#build-sstate-cache) and [`TMPDIR`](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/singleindex.html#term-TMPDIR) not erased.